# Sparklyr : How to avoid spilling on disk when computing new tables with little memory available?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Currently I am working on a 6 GB dataset with sparklyr 1.0 on local mode ran on a virtual machine with 26GB of ram and 4 cores, but ultimately the goal is to be able to run the whole routine on a cluster to handle a 100GB dataset.

I am setting up a verification process on the dataset which leads to the creation of a bunch of intermediary tables.

To quicken the computations I am caching some of these tables in memory but because of the limited ram there is some spilling on disk which significantly slows the computations, and I am trying to limit it.

The most memory intensive part is when I create a 6GB table from another 6GB table that I need to cache because I do a lot of calculations on it later.

The code looks like this :

```
table1 <- spark_read_csv(..., memory = T)

...
table2 <- Some calculations based on table1 
...

sdf_register(sc,table2)
tbl_uncache(sc,table1)
tbl_cache(sc,table2)
```

*My configuration :*

```
conf <- spark_config()
conf["spark.serializer"] <- "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
conf["sparklyr.shell.driver-memory"] <- "16G" 
conf["spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"] <- 12L
conf["spark.memory.fraction"] <- 0.90
conf["spark.memory.storagefraction"] <- 0.80
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf)
```

The spilling happens either during the calculations, as I guess execution is taking memory from storage which forces the spill on disk, or during the caching of table2 which I am trying to avoid by uncaching first.

But looking at the jobs generated by this code, it looks like table2 is computed for the sdf_register and again for the tbl_cache which does not seem efficient to me.

Is there a better way to do it ?

Or can I simply tune my configuration differently to avoid spilling ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the `data.table` package? Since all your data fits in RAM on a single server, Spark is not the optimal tool for the job here -- all the architectural design choices were made to facilitate with massive workloads that require distribution, but when running on a single machine, it's hilariously inefficient both in CPU and RAM usage. Heck, even base `R` data.frames might be more performant in this case.

Comment: @MattSummersgill alright thanks for pointing this out, I'll clarify.

What I'm working on from a broader perspective is updating a piece of code originally written in data.table so that it can handle much larger datasets. 

The objective dataset if 100GB large and goes far above the hardcoded data.table limit, which is the whole reason for what I am doing.

I figured out it would be best to start working locally on a smaller dataset to tune everything before working on a cluster, but that might not be the best course of action.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- if you want to get a minimum viable working implementation locally before deploying to the full cluster, perhaps trying to reduce your data set even further might help you get through refactoring without resource constraints, then you could focus on tuning once you have the full resources of the distributed system -- communication overhead, data locality, and other factors will require drastically different optimizations than a single node run anyway.

Comment: Alright thank you for your answer, I have a reached a point where it's working without major crash and I will be satisfied with that until I have access to the full ressources.